# How to parameterize a $resource call in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have this factory:

```
angular.module('core.actor').factory('Actor', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/actor/:actorId/', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                cache: true
            },    
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

And this is part of my paging function:

```
if (self.pk == "-6" && self.searchTerm == undefined) {
    self.actorsToAdd = Actor.query({
        offset: pageOffset,
        limit: pageLimit
    })
} else if (self.pk == "-6") {
    self.actorsToAdd = Actor.query({
        offset: pageOffset,
        limit: pageLimit,
        search: self.searchTerm
    })
} else if (self.searchTerm == undefined) {
    self.actorsToAdd = Actor.query({
        offset: pageOffset,
        limit: pageLimit,
        pk: self.pk.toString()
    })
} else {
    self.actorsToAdd = Actor.query({
        offset: pageOffset,
        limit: pageLimit,
        search: self.searchTerm,
        pk: self.pk.toString()
    })
}
```

It changes the GET request generated by Actor depending on certain conditions. I'm looking for a way to parametrize this function so I would be able to replace 'Actor' with a variable.

Something along the lines of:

```
pageType = Movie;

var page = function (pageType){

  self.itemsToAdd = pageType.query({
      offset: pageOffset,
      limit: pageLimit
  })  
}
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Yes it is possible. add `params` and pass whole object according to your request. find docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give me an example? I'm not clear where I should make the changes. According to the docs it seems that the params  should be defined in the 'Actor' factory.

Comment: Have your factory do more than return just one `$resource`...think of `Movies` factory that returns all the resources needed ... Actor, Movie, Genre etc

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks! Again, an example would be greatly appreciated. From what I understand the factory returns a single $resource, that access a single API path. How would I go about making this factory return multiple $resources ?

Comment: Can put all the resources in one object and either return that or return  function that takes resource name as argument and it returns the appropriate one from the object

Comment: Most factories will look like `return { propName1: /* func, object, variable or value */,  propName2: /* func,object, variable or value */}`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it, rather than passing individual parameters into the query, pass in a object, which contains your query parameters.

```
angular.module('core.actor').factory('Actor', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
     return $resource('api/actor/:actorId/', {}, {
       query: {
       method: 'GET',
       isArray: true,
       cache: true,
       params: { queryParams: '@_queryParams' }
    },
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
}
]);
```

so your call to it looks like this

```
Actor.query({ queryParams: {
    offset: pageOffset,
    limit: pageLimit,
    pk: self.pk.toString()
}})
```

Then on the server I look at which values are contained in my (json parsed) params, in order to construct the appropriate query on the database.

After your latest comment, is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

```
angular.module('core.actor').factory('Api', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return {
      actor: $resource('api/actor/:actorId/', {}, {
        query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true,
      cache: true,
      params: {queryParams: '@_queryParams'}
    },
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  }),
  movie: $resource('api/move/:moveId/', {}, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
          isArray: true,
          cache: true,
          params: {queryParams: '@_queryParams'}
        },
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        }
      })
    };
  }
]);
```

You could then call either Api.movie.query() or Api.actor.query()

For completeness, heres how my server side code looks when building my query.

```
var constructUserQuery = function (queryParams) {
  var query = { $or: [], $and: [] };

  if (queryParams.name) {
    query.$and.push({ displayName: { $regex: queryParams.name,     $options: 'i'} });
  }

  if (queryParams.client) {
    query.$or.push({ client: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(queryParams.client) });
  }

  if (queryParams.roles) {
    query.$or.push({ roles: { $in: queryParams.roles }});
  }

  // Ignore the current user, if it's supplied
  if (queryParams.user) {
    query.$and.push({ _id: { $ne: queryParams.user._id }});
  }

  // Clean up any empty arrays
  if (query.$or.length === 0) {
    delete query.$or;
  }

  if (query.$and.length === 0) {
    delete query.$and;
  }

  return query;
};
```

Obviously this is specific to my case but you get the idea. This is the only place where I have any if statements.

Comment: Yes, but how will this help me replace the 'Actor' factory with a different factory ?

Comment: You're making assumptions that all your factories accept the same parameters?

Comment: Sudgen Basically yes, the only thing that is different are the API urls

Comment: I've updated my answer with another way to do it, which I think is what charliefl was suggesting

Comment: I'll try this out and see if I'll manage to get it to work. But let me see if I understand what you are saying,You idea is skipping all the if statements in the paging function and send all the params to the server what ever they may be and let the server figure out what to return. Won't it just place the if statements on the server side?

Comment: If you're supplying any number of potential query combinations it makes sense to construct your query as close to the data as possible, where you have more knowledge of how your data is structured.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm still having trouble understanding how will this help me use the same paging function for both $resources. The logic for the paging function is the same except the name of the resource. With your solution, I will have to call Api.movie.query()  instead of Movie.query() but I will still have to use two different functions for actor and movie paging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117918/discussion-between-matt-sugden-and-curtwagner1984).